# How can I determine the transfer function of this servomechanism system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, transfer-theory

How can I find transfer function of the given servomechanism system with input $V$(voltage) and output $θ_L$(angle of the load). Schematic of the system is given below.

[Schematic of the servomechanism system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mpc/ug/motorschematic.gif)

There are two differential equations of the given system.
$$\dot{\omega}_L=-\dfrac{k_T}{J_L}\left[θ_L-\dfrac{1}{\rho}θ_M\right]-\dfrac{β_L}{J_L}\omega_L$$
$$\dot{\omega}_M=\dfrac{k_M}{RJ_M}\left[V-k_M\omega_M\right]-\dfrac{β_M}{J_M}\omega_M+\dfrac{k_T}{ρJ_M}\left[θ_L-\dfrac{1}{\rho}θ_M\right] $$

$k_T, J_L, ρ, k_M, J_M, β_L, β_M $ and $R$ are positive constants. In this case, $$F(s)=\dfrac{θ_L(s)}{V(s)}$$ has to be found.

Comment: I edited your question. Please be more careful in your Mathjax typesetting you are using $w$ instead of $\omega$ (\omega) which lead to confusions in the question. And also consider using \dfrac{}{} for fractions instead of typing them with /.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\dot{\theta}_L=\omega_L$ and $\dot{\theta}_M=\omega_M$, then we obtain:

$$\ddot{\theta}_L=-\dfrac{k_T}{J_L}\left[θ_L-\dfrac{1}{\rho}θ_M\right]-\dfrac{β_L}{J_L}\dot{\theta}_L$$
$$\ddot{\theta}_M=\dfrac{k_M}{RJ_M}\left[V-k_M\dot{\theta}_M\right]-\dfrac{β_M}{J_M}\dot{\theta}_M+\dfrac{k_T}{ρJ_M}\left[θ_L-\dfrac{1}{\rho}θ_M\right] $$

The Laplace transform of the first equation results in

$$\theta_L=\dfrac{\dfrac{k_T}{\rho J_L}}{s^2+\dfrac{\beta_L}{J_L}s+\dfrac{k_T}{J_L}}\theta_M=\dfrac{k_T}{\rho J_Ls^3+\rho\beta_Ls+\rho k_T}\theta_M$$

or

$$\theta_M=\dfrac{\rho J_Ls^3+\rho\beta_Ls+\rho k_T}{k_T}\theta_L.\qquad \qquad (1)$$

The Laplace transform of the second equation is given by

$$\left[s^2+\left(\dfrac{k^2_M}{RJ_M}+\dfrac{\beta_M}{J_M} \right)s+\dfrac{k_T}{\rho^2J_M}\right]\theta_M = \dfrac{k_T}{\rho J_M}\theta_L+\dfrac{k_M}{RJ_M}V \qquad (2)$$

Now, we $(1)$ into $(2)$:

$$\left[s^2+\left(\dfrac{k^2_M}{RJ_M}+\dfrac{\beta_M}{J_M} \right)s+\dfrac{k_T}{\rho^2J_M}\right]\dfrac{\rho J_Ls^3+\rho\beta_Ls+\rho k_T}{k_T}\theta_L = \dfrac{k_T}{\rho J_M}\theta_L+\dfrac{k_M}{RJ_M}V.$$

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: I found the answer as:

Comment: I took $k_T=1280.2, k_M=10, J_M=0.5, J_L=2.5, \rho=20, β_M=0.1, β_L=25$ and $R=20$ to show stability of the system. I used step function of MATLAB to get step response but system acted like unstable system. However in this link, system is shown as stable: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mpc/ug/servomechanism-controller.html?requestedDomain=true). What do I do wrong?

Comment: There should be a constant term in the denominator. At the moment your system is marginally stable, see the pole at $s=0$, which explains that your step function leads to an increasing response.